# Snowmaking in the tropics - an estimate of water evaporation

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, condensed-matter

If I set up a snowmaker in the tropics and sprayed water with it how much water would I evaporate?  How would I calculate?

Comment: you would need to know humidity, droplet size and temperature.  Of course all the water will evaporate eventually if humidity is <100%, do you mean before hitting the ground?

Comment: There are snow-covered mountains in the tropical latitudes!

Comment: It's common in outdoor spaces in Texas, Arizona, and other warm locales to put misters outdoors. As soon as it hits you it evaporates and cools you off. Of course, if the weather is really humid it doesn't work so well.